# How to solve normal recaptcha in 2captcha.com using python?

Tags: python, python-requests, captcha, 2captcha

I'm trying to solve a https://2captcha.com/demo/normal using python code before implementing it on my project. But, I'm a little bit confused about how I should send my image captcha.

Here's the code of how the form I should submit to obtain the problem id:

```
<form method="post" action="https://2captcha.com/in.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="post" />
Your key:
<input type="text" name="key" value="YOUR_APIKEY" />
The CAPTCHA file:
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload and get the ID" />
```

and here's the image URL that I want to solve:

```
https://2captcha.com/dist/web/99581b9d446a509a0a01954438a5e36a.jpg
```

I intend to make a post request using Python code into 2captcha.com (using requests library) to get the problem id, like this

```
OK|2122988149
```

I really appreciate any people who can help.

Comment: It's a paid service so you should be asking their customer service. They also have [documentation](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api), including a [demo page](https://2captcha.com/demo).

Comment: I've been trying to send some request with payload={"key":"MY_API_KEY","file":"target_image"} and after make a request.post, it return `ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE`

Comment: If you want to use python, you should follow their python example, not their manual example.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the example given in your link:

```
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
solver = TwoCaptcha('your_key')
ele = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@alt,'captcha example')]")[0]
result = solver.normal(file=ele.get_attribute('src'))
print(result)
```